# Is there a way to add a extra user interface into an IPA?

Tags: ios

Let say I want to modify enterprise apps that my users uses, these are enterprise apps developed by a different company. Is there any ways to add an executable code for example an extra password screen before you can actually enter the APP?  If so, how would you do it?

I've tried to look at the entry point of the main, but I'm not sure how to reroute the extra code I've written as the main entry instead of the original main entry.

Comment: IPA is just zip. You can easily extract the program from it and patch the executable. You may have to re-sign it though.

Comment: Ok I've tried to rephrase it, hopefully is more clear.

Comment: You'll need the source code to modify the app.

Comment: Actually no, there is this thing in the IT/MDM space called "App Wrapping" where the IT would take compiled IPA's(Must be enterprise IPAs) and they add an extra password screen before it can launch the app. http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/jackmadden/archive/2012/06/08/app-wrapping-with-mocana-mobile-app-protection.aspx

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt How do I easily do that? Is there certain methods to this?

Comment: @mskw Patching binaries is never easy.

Comment: What methods are usually used to patch executables?